# Disable multiple websocket connection from the same webbrowser tab

Tags: java, websocket

is there any way to block / close multiple websocket connection from the same browser tab for a client?

I'm creating simple card game using javax.websocket in a backend and pure js in frontend. In the app I'm not going to use any login and password authentication system.
I'm looking for some method where I can close second connection if the client is already connected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would work if there was some kind of unique identifier for each player (ie. authorization token).

Otherwise you could check their IPs, whether they are already connected and disconnect them if so. This can be easily bypassed, and there arise issues when there's multiple clients from one router.

Comment: Is there a solution that guarantees no bypassing , or is it something impossible to do?

Comment: It's impossible to do. That's where anonymous online polls suffer the most. You could introduce some measurements to make sure the user is unique (such as: user agent matching from the same IP, cookies, etc.) but they can be bypassed by advanced users.